# In hosted TFS environment change process from Scrum to Kanban in current project?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I am looking for guidance on process template switching.

Is this the best help page for change methology in an ongoing project?:

https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/process/manage-process

We are using the hosted (online) version of TFS, and would like to work WIP-limited and contiuous planning (Kanban) instead of time-boxed (Scrum), because we are a very small team and have rapidly changing requirements.

I guess this means we need to change our current process template from Scrum to Agile, correct? And that this not possible to do for an ongoing tfs project. You can start a new project but then you will loose all history.

But I have seen a help page showing that you can import new templates to an existing project, and that will make the same changes for you as starting a new project would have done.

Victor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is quite broad, but I'll do my best...

> We are using the hosted (online) version of TFS, and would like to
>   work WIP-limited and contiuous planning (Kanban) instead of time-boxed
>   (Scrum), because we are a very small team and have rapidly changing
>   requirements.

You've not outlined the process of how you work or what you need, but if you want to use a Kanban Process you should be able to use the "Board" under "WORK" and set WIP limits on columns using the "Configuration" options there:

[image]

You can then customise columns and WIP limits:[image]

> I guess this means we need to change our current process template from
>   Scrum to Agile, correct? And that this not possible to do for an
>   ongoing tfs project. You can start a new project but then you will
>   loose all history.

There's no need to change, see [this post](https://nkdagility.com/choosing-a-process-template-for-your-team-project/) from Marin Hinshelwood where he says:

> TL;DR – Select the Scrum template if you have an agile team and want
>   to reduce friction. Don’t create unnecessary friction for your move to
>   agility by selecting either the CMMI or Agile templates that suffer
>   from the legacy of the Microsoft Solution Framework (MSF).

This takes me back to the original question:

> Is this the best help page for change methology in an ongoing
>   project?:

The answers is **yes, BUT** only if you need to make heavy customisations, start by changing the Kanban board in the "Board" view and only come back to the Process Template customisation if you need to make more changes. You can add / change Kanban columns instead of adding "states".

Comment: Great answer. Just what I needed to know!